# Transforming an array into matrix in php

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I am trying to write a code for Rokudoku (a 6x6 version of Sudoku).

I have already prepared table for Rokudoku; meaning I don't have to generate Rokudoku table every time.

Here is my constructor:

```
const row = 6, column=6;
public $grid_number;
public $numbers=array(); 


function __construct()
{
   (...some code...)

    $this->numbers=array(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 
                         3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0,  
                         0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
                         0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0);

    foreach ($numbers as $element)
        for($i = 1; $i < Rokudoku::row+1; $i++)
            for($j = 1; $j < Rokudoku::column+1; $j++)
                $this->grid_number[$i][$j] = $element;



    }
```

My question is: How can I transform an array into the matrix so that later I can access each number as [row][column] since my idea is not working.

For example, number 4 in an array is: grid_number[1][3].

Sorry if this is a trivial question. This is a beginner's work. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Rokudoku, but consider the following example:

```
$numbers = array(
    0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0,
    3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0,
    0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2,
    0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0);

function getNumber($numbers, $row, $column){

    $position = $row * 6 - (6 - $column); // the two 6s are your consts.
    return $numbers[$position - 1]; // -1 because arrays count from 0, not 1.
};

$number = getNumber($numbers, 1, 3);
```

Your array, even though it *looks* like a matrix is just a list of numbers that you can also write down like `[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0];`. When realising this, you can write a simple function like I did with `getNumber` to find the right element with a simple calculation.

You can see a working example [here](https://3v4l.org/4mP3r).

Comment: You had hardcoded rows and columns size in your method.
I think it's not good idea for reusing of that code.
But idea is really good. You retrive exaclly that element as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

```
<?php

    $row = $col = 6;

    $numbers = [
        0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 
        3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0,  
        0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
        0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0
    ];

    $result = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
        $y = intdiv($i, $col);
        $x = $y * $col + ($i % $row) % $row;
        $result[$y][$x] = $numbers[$i];
    }

    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `array_chunk()` to split the array up...

```
$rowSize = 6;

$numbers = [
    0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0,
    3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0,
    0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2,
    0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0
];

$result = array_chunk($numbers, $rowSize);
print_r($result);
```

The only issue with this is that arrays are then 0 based, so 4 will be [0,2] and not [1,3].